# How to write non code documentation in sandcastle

Tags: c#, sandcastle, maml

I'm documenting my c# code using Sandcastle, but I'm unable to figure out how to do things like guides, Q&A, or other general information.

I created a namespace that doesn't get included in the project but builds documentation where I store guides. The class becomes the header, but the title have "class" in the name and includes a c# definition which is not appropriate.

I can see that you can add and create some files from the Project Explorer, but they do not appear in the project when building. The files a also primarily AML files, something that is not as easy to write as I would like as I'm unable to find a tool for non-data focused editing.

[image]

Comment: Sandcastle generates documentation from code comments, will be hard to get it working with guides, Q/As.

Answer (score 1):

It's not what it's intended for, it's just a tool to automatically build a public API documentation. It's roots are in MSDN like help file generation.

> unable to figure out how to do things like guides, Q&A, or other general information.

For more flexible content you'd need something like :

https://docusaurus.io/

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for, as I want the documentation to be self-contained as a single site with API doc and general doc.
One solution would be a post-processing script to modify the output so that it looks right.